# What is the difference between src, public, and build in folder structure?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, browser, working-directory, svelte-3

I know what these files contain like build contains the minified file which is minified from src file. I need to know how browser works with it. I haven't uploaded my build file to hosting service yet my website got rendered. In the website, `<script>` SRC was linked to build but there was no build uploaded but a build was created automatically. this behaviour was observed in svelte. But I hope all framework does the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the Vercel documentation found here https://vercel.com/docs/build-step "Vercel tries to automatically detect the frontend framework you’re using for your project and configure the project settings for you. If you’d like to override the settings or specify a different framework, you can do so from the Build & Development Settings section." So Vercel did automatically make a build folder for you. This is ok, because you should always use `npm run build` to create your build folder and point your hosting to use this folder for production.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, build tools like webpack, parcel, ...etc., use **BUILD** or **DIST** (Of course you can change it however you want) folder to store production ready build files of the project.

Files in **PUBLIC** are just copy & pasted to the build/dist folder when build process is finished. You can store index html, images, fonts, favicon or other static text files in there. They are not processed by build tools.

**SRC** folder is just for storing the whole project's unminified source code.

Most frameworks use '*build/dist - src - public*' structure while frameworks like next.js uses root for storing project source code by default.

Comment: so this is my scenario with the svelte app I build. I used vercel to host the app which used my github repo. the repo doesn't have any build file. but the hosted app has the build file inside the browser source. does vercel do npm build automatically and host the website??

Comment: @kishoreRajendran yes, it does